Can a Small Beast Master Ranger ride its Primal Companion as an Independent Mount?
The rules for Mounted Combat stipulate that a Medium creature with suitable anatomy can serve as a Small creature's mount:

A willing creature that is at least one size larger than a rider and that has an appropriate anatomy can serve as a mount.

As long as the stat block is appropriate, the Beast Master's Primal Companion can be a Medium animal of the Ranger's choosing:

Choose its stat block: Beast of the Land, Beast of the Sea, or Beast of the Sky. You also determine the kind of animal it is, choosing a kind appropriate for the stat block.

A trained animal can be a controlled mount:

You can control a mount only if it has been trained to accept a rider. Domesticated horses, mules, and similar creatures have such training.

Otherwise, a mount is independent:

An independent mount—one that lets you ride but ignores your control—retains its place in the Initiative order and moves and acts as it likes.

Technically, then, an untrained Primal Companion (e.g., a wolf) should be run as an independent mount.
However, the Primal Companion obeys the Ranger's commands:

The beast is Friendly to you and your allies and obeys your commands.

and moves on the Ranger's turn:

The Beast in Combat. In combat, the beast acts during your turn. It can move and use its Reaction on its own...

This suggests that a Ranger could gain most, if not all, of the benefits of a controlled mount while technically maintaining the beast's independence.
So, if an untrained, willing, Medium Primal Companion served as a mount, could it be run as an independent mount? And, is this balanced?

It depends
The key here is that the mount has either “been trained to accept a rider” or not. If it has, it’s controled, if it isn’t, it isn’t. The fact that it otherwise acts at your direction is immaterial.
So, when you “determine the kind of animal it is”, if it is one that has been trained (e.g. horse) it’s controllable, if it isn’t (e.g. wolf), it’s independent. Remember, you don’t have to control a controllable mount, you make that choice when you mount it (“You can control a mount …”).
If you have the Animal Handling proficiency, you could train an untrained mount and, until you replaced it, it would remain trained. Strictly, if you went back to a Beast of the Land, it would be a new (untrained) beast, but a kind DM might allow you to re-summon the original (trained) beast.

This seems right to me. Sometimes it would benefit to be a controlled mount.

The companion is not an independent mount
You quote already what an independent mount is:

An independent mount—one that lets you ride but ignores your control—retains its place in the Initiative order and moves and acts as it likes.

The companion quote you provided is cut short. It continues:

In combat, the beast acts
during your turn. It can move and use its Reaction on its own, but the only action it takes is the Dodge action unless you take a Bonus Action to command it to take an action in its stat block or some other action.

The companion acts according to your command, not as it likes. It also does not retain its own place in the initiative order but acts on your turn. So on more than one count it does not qualify as an independent mount, and thus isn’t one.
(You maybe could argue that it does retain its place in the initiative order, that just happens to be on your turn, but I think that is sophistry, and even if you accepted that, it still cannot act as it likes but acts as you command. If the authors had wanted the companion to be an independent creature, it would have been easy enough to state it acts independently of you but is friendly to you).

This sounds like a RAI argument, but without any support for the intent.

Also, this answer could be improved by providing support for the rules that enable the companion to be a controlled mount. Only an animal that has been trained to accept a rider can serve as a controlled mount, and there is no precedent for assuming that Primal Companion has had such training. Additionally, the beast can act on its own: If you have the Incapacitated condition, the beast acts on its own and isn’t limited to the Dodge action.

@nonymous Not sure what you mean with "without any support". I am quoting the text of the feature. The description of the beast just does not fit an independent mount.

The description of the beast doesn't fit a controlled mount, either. So, your choice between them is arbitrary and unsupported. The fact that the beast obeys commands has no necessary relationship to its autonomy as a mount. Analogously, an autonomous vehicle might "obey my commands" to transport me somewhere without requiring me to drive it; an independent mount might obey my command to take me "over there" without requiring me to control it. Moreover, the only want to "control" it is with training, which it lacks. Finally, the beast definitely acts on its own, e.g. when you're incapacitated.

@nonymous You seem quite convinced already what the right answer is. How about you post a self-answer with your take on it? It will give you more space to argue your view, and will not be ephemeral like these comments are.
